# Switching RX and TX of RS232 level shifter

Tags: raspberry-pi, rs232

I am using a RS232 level shifting board with a raspberry pi. The board is connected to the pi using VCC, ground, RxOut->UART-Rx and TxIn->UART-Tx.
I try to avoid buying a null-modem-cable, can I just switch the jumpers between the pi and the level shifting board?

Answer (score 1):

Switching the RX and TX connections to the logic-level side of the board will not change the RS-232 level input to an output or vice-versa.

Instead you'll be connecting an input to an input (useless) and an output to an output (useless, and possibly harmful).

Answer (score 1):

We don't know which board you have, but changing wiring on the board is wrong solution, and it still won't change the connector gender and it won't change which pins a are inputs and outputs on the connector.

So if a null modem cable has correct connectors then you should buy one.

Also small null modem plugs exist to adapt a normal cable to a null modem cable.

If you anyway need some DE-9 connectors and a cable, you could just buy correct connectors for the job.

Answer (score 1):

No, the RS22 level shifters are unidirectional. if the connector has the wrong pinout you'll need to adapt that. "dupont" wires will work in a pinch.